# Are width and height anchors required in Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, constraints

I've a Swift UIKit Component with dynamic sizing, am I required to specify it's width and height anchors in the parent view? If yes, then how?

Comment: Depends. Can you attach a screenshot of your current layout?

Comment: @aheze as a part of my NDA I cannot disclose anything, what I can do is: Basically I've a chevron.backward on the top left of the screen, the icon is embedded inside a UIView, what I basically want is to not set the height and width anchor of the ui view in the parent view... does that make sense?

Comment: So do you want the parent view to be stuck to the edges of the image? Btw "as a part of my NDA I cannot disclose anything" - try making an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead.

Comment: @aheze thanks mate for your help! I found a fix for my problem, and have outlined it in my answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Basically, inside my UIView, I had a UIButton which had a UIImage, and as I specified the UIImage was an SF Symbol with size, which I calculated like this: `UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1).pointSize`, note: the `.title1` can be any `UIFont.TextStyle` value.

Then what I did was, I created a Utility Method inside my UIView class, which basically returned `UIImage.size`, and then I called this inside my constraints method in the parent view, and the set the width and height anchor to the value from this variable.

Everything works as expected now!